# WebGL alpha depending on distance from origin

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, webgl

I have the following setup:
[image]

The plane grid consists of lines, with brighter dots where lines intersect. I would like to introduce an alpha gradient on the entire scene, with the current alpha (0.2) at the very centre, linearly fading to 0.0 at the edges. The only examples I can find online end up doing nothing but changing the background to a random colour depending on the near/far values.

I'm looking for something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92LEU.png

How can I achieve this? Here are the grid shaders:

vertex:

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 uv;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
varying vec2 vUv;

int scale = 1;

void main()
{
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projection * view * model * position * vec4(scale, scale, scale, 1);
}
```

fragment:

```
precision mediump float;

vec2 spacing = vec2(32, 32);
varying vec2 vUv;

int scale = 1;

void main()
{
        float scaleFactor = 32.0 * 8.0 * float(scale);
        float offX = scaleFactor * vUv.x;
        float offY = scaleFactor * vUv.y;

        int remX = int(mod(offX, spacing[0]));
        int remY = int(mod(offY, spacing[1]));

        if (remX == 0 || remY == 0)
        {
                if (remX == remY)
                {
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.2);
                }
                else
                {
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.05);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        }
}
```

The cubes use a different, basic shader - I will also want these affected by the fog. Will I just have to copy the fog logic to that shader and manipulate gl_FragColor's alpha in the same way?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the alpha channel depending on the distance from the center. The `vUv` cooridante of the center is (0.5, 0.5). Compute the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) using the [`length`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/length.xhtml) function and set the alpha channel as a function of this distance:

```c
void main()
{
    // [...]    


    if (remX == 0 || remY == 0)
    {
        float dist = length(vUv - vec2(0.5));     
        float alpha = (1.0 - 2.0*dist) * 0.2;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
    }
    else
    {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I modified the distance mapping to allow any min/max alpha value rather than 0.0 -> 0.1 - I'll leave it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to the accepted answer - I modified the distance -> alpha mapping to allow for any min/max alpha.

It looks like this:

[image]

```
precision mediump float;

vec2 spacing = vec2(32, 32);
varying vec2 vUv;

int scale = 32;

// fog scale describes the amount of space where the fog's opacity is affected by the linear interpolation. larger fog scale = larger gradient
int fog_scale = 2;

float map(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max)
{
        return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

float get_distance_alpha(float min, float max)
{
        float dist = length(vUv - vec2(0.5)) * float(scale) / float(fog_scale);
        return map(dist, 0.0, 0.5, max, min); // at origin: max; at edge: min
}

void main()
{
        float scaleFactor = 32.0 * 8.0 * float(scale);
        float offX = scaleFactor * vUv.x;
        float offY = scaleFactor * vUv.y;

        int remX = int(mod(offX, spacing[0]));
        int remY = int(mod(offY, spacing[1]));

        if (remX == 0 || remY == 0)
        {
                if (remX == remY)
                {
//                      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, get_distance_alpha(0.0, 0.5));
                }
                else
                {
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, get_distance_alpha(0.0, 0.2));
                }
        }
        else
        {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        }
}
```